# Python Selenium, Firefox profiles

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python selenium and I need more explanation on the effect of the below code on selenium Firefox profile.

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('application/vnd.ms-excel'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox browser is by default asking if to save or to open the file when user tries to download a file.
To prevent Firefox opening that dialog we can predefine not to ask this for predefined types of files.
Each file type should be mentioned explicitly with such setting in order to not ask when downloading of such a kind of file initiated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when setting up your Firefox profile you add a call to set the property `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` like this.

You won't face download pop up.

so basically it means that download any file and save it to the desired location using Selenium Webdriver.